# Issue with printing data to a table from a database

Tags: php, postgresql

i would like to to display a table but all I've got is a message that contains: Resource id #5,
my session.php contains my db connection and some user information, I've used it at other pages so i don't think it's the cause.
i'm a not a pro with the web :3  .
here is my code:

```
<?php  
include('session.php');
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$result = pg_query($db,"SELECT * FROM public.antennas WHERE idop IN (SELECT idop FROM public.user WHERE username_u='$username' ) ");
      return $result; 
 $output = '';  
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="10%">Id Antennas</th>  
                </tr>';  
 if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["id_a"].'</td>  
                     <td class="id_a" data-id1="'.$row["id_a"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["id_a"].'</td>   
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id7="'.$row["id_a"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '  
           <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td id="id_a" contenteditable></td>  
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
      echo 'success';
       }  
 else  
 {  
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                     </tr>';
                     echo 'problem';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
      </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

Comment: You might want to remove `return $result; `

Answer (score 3):

You have `return $result;` on Line 5.

Remove it, you're forcing the PHP script to exit therefore everything after the return is not executed

Comment: Happy to help, don't forget to approve the answer :)

Comment: i'd like to, but they said : Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: You can now, just remember to take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven already